# SMD jumper / 0R resistor with long thin package?

Tags: packages

I need 0R "resistor" with long and thin package for surface mount.

Is there something like "2405" (like 0805 but 3x longer) size package or something similar?

I just want to "jump" over few traces on 1-layer circuit board and avoid whole drilling process.

Comment: There's 2512 resistors available in 0Ω...  5mm space between pads.

Comment: @Kamil  Is this for production or for a one-off prototype?

Comment: @NickAlexeev For small series manual production. For prototypes I can make holes and piece of wire.

Comment: @Majenko I was thinking about 2512, but its... pretty wide. I was wondering if something long and narrow exists. EvangelosEm links in answer show some interesting jumpers.

Comment: You can use SMT fuses from Littelfuse, Link http://www.littelfuse.com/products/fuses/surface-mount-fuses.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find smt jumper pins which can be up to 12mm long and are made for this purpose. Most major suppliers have them. You can also get up to 2512, 0Ω resistors but pay attention to the current rating.

Some examples from DigiKey include smt jumpers from [Keystone](http://www.digikey.co.uk/product-search/en?vendor=0&keywords=keystone+shunt), [Harwin](http://www.digikey.co.uk/product-search/en/connectors-interconnects/shunts-jumpers/?k=harwin%20jumper) and [others](http://www.digikey.co.uk/product-search/en/connectors-interconnects/shunts-jumpers/?k=shunt). They are a bit expensive but they can handle more current than a 0Ω resistor.
An alternative would be [0Ω resistors](http://www.digikey.co.uk/product-search/en?pv1291=3297&pv1291=1791&pv1291=2290&pv1291=983&pv1291=684&FV=fff40001%2Cfff800e9%2C40400&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25) if your current handling requirements aren't very high. These can be down to a cent.

Just use you supplier of choice, play around with the search parameters and something will eventually pop up.

**Edit:**
Some datasheets provide a power rating for the 0Ω resistors. You can also have a look at [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/43360/how-to-calculate-power-rating-for-zero-ohm-resistors) discussion on the power rating for 0Ω resistors. If in doubt, it's probably best to contact the manufacturer and ask them to clarify.

Comment: I don't think I can provide links to specific products but they are very easy to find.

Comment: Providing links and even better pictures etc. is acceptable as long as there is attribution.

Comment: try http://www.keyelco.com/product.cfm/product_id/14013 - 12.3mm jumper

Comment: @placeholder thanks for the info. I was looking for a reference to a rule regarding the subject in the about page but could find none. Here is an example search on Digikey http://www.digikey.co.uk/product-search/en/connectors-interconnects/shunts-jumpers/?k=jumper%20tin%20smd

Comment: Power rating of a 2512 0\$\Omega\$ "resistor" does not make much sense. Maybe you mean current rating?

Comment: @EvangelosEm: Wow, those Digi-Key units are *expensive*! Almost 10 cents apiece, even in qty 5000.

Comment: @DaveTweed: Yeah, they are a pretty expensive for what they are. An alternative would be [0Ω resistors](http://www.digikey.co.uk/product-search/en?pv1291=3297&pv1291=1791&pv1291=2290&pv1291=983&pv1291=684&FV=fff40001%2Cfff800e9%2C40400&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25) if your current handling requirements aren't very high. These can be down to a cent. [These](http://www.digikey.co.uk/product-search/en?vendor=0&keywords=keystone+shunt) are the Keystone ones. Just play around with the parameters and something will eventually pop up.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: It seemed weird for a manufacturer to specify a wattage rating for a 0Ω resistor so I looked around and every manufacturer uses this value in a different way. Some don't have it (which makes sense), others use the maximum ohmic value of the jumpers, some use it as an indication for size, others just don't bother to add a note to say the value doesn't apply to the jumpers. I haven't found any compelling answer about the power rating of a 0Ω resistor anywhere so I edited my answer to point to the correct discussions.