# Identify this SMT device

Tags: components, surface-mount

Can anyone tell me what are these smt devices. Especially the one with square drawn at centre[image: Here is my pcb image]

Comment: Measure the resistance of them (in circuit) with a DMM.  They should all be zero ohms.  In which case they are zero ohm links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are zero ohm links. Maybe mainly used as jumpers on this single sided board to allow for a track to run under them, but they have other uses, see [What is the usage of Zero Ohm & MiliOhm Resistor?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/42756/what-is-the-usage-of-zero-ohm-miliohm-resistor)